# Load appropriate spring bean dynamically at runtime

Tags: java, spring

I need to dynamically load a spring bean based on certain condition. I am calling an external service. If the service returns true , I need to inject bean a and I need to inject bean b otherwise. Both bean a and bean b implement the same interface. I am using spring 4.1.4 but not spring boot.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are not using Spring Boot, I suppose you could try something like this:

```
@Lazy
@Bean("myBean1")
public MyBean getBean1() { return new MyBean1();}

@Lazy
@Bean("myBean2")
public MyBean getBean2() { return new MyBean2();}

private void myFunction(ApplicationContext context) {
    MyBean myBean;

    if(condition == true) {
        myBean = context.getBean("myBean1");
    } else {
        myBean = context.getBean("myBean2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take your conditional, put it within an if statement, then return whichever bean you want.

```
MyInterface myBean = null;
if(conditional == true){
  myBean = context.getBean(BeanA.class);
}else{
  myBean = context.getBean(BeanB.class);
}
return myBean;
```

Comment: How is that different from the answer I gave? Excluding the detail of using the class instead of the bean name it's exactly the same answer.